# Multiple receive and awaiting for request with similar ID received from before executing the function inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sockets

Could you please help me with solving the following problem I would like to get values from the array returned by the socket which have similar ID's and pass them to a function.

```
First Received Request 

{
 "ID":"4567132",
 "GroupType":"2"
 "Name":"John Chris"
 "SocialID":"68799"
 "SecurityID":"18799-er7ree-781347a-71237n"
}


Second Received Request 

{
 "ID":"4567438",
 "GroupType":"2" 
 "SocialID":"68799"
 "SecurityID":"68789-4d37er-98c5347-e05d9b"
}

I would like to get the following Expected Results combined from the First and Second. But taking into consideration other request also coming in from the api.
{
 "GroupType":"2" 
 "SocialID":"68799"
 "PublicSecurityID":"18799-er7ree-781347a-71237n"
 "PrivateSecurityID":"68789-4d37er-98c5347-e05d9b"
}
```

What make things complicated is that both first and second are received at the same time and maybe there can be other request the would be received by the socket. How can I group only those incoming messages that have a similar SocialID. Also how can I await for all the similar request from the socket and only execute once there are no more request.

Here is the code for receiving the socket

```
ReceiveSocket.on("socketMessage", (returnedData) => {
    // code here       
});
```

I'm not sure how to approach the problem logically could you explain and give the solution to handling the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I would probably persist these json in db, and whenever there is new request I would query db by SocialID, and if data exist there,
I would merge them to generate the desired output save in db permanently.
Even if two requests are around sometime, there should be some milliseconds difference and the mechanism should work

Comment: @Prakash noted for the persist of json in the db, but I don't have access to the db its just a third party that lets me receive the message. Would there be another way to handle this?

Comment: @John Is `returnedData` a single object or is it an array containing objects? Do you need to group every single incoming JSON according to their `SocialID` value or is it something limited to only a few "special" `SocialID`s? Will you call the function that makes use of the values in the same file where the values are received? This is running on a Node environment, right?

Comment: @Lual returnData is only an array containing objects. Yes I  need to group every single incoming JSON according to their SocialID value. Its like I receive a message. Yes I may pass the received value or process it in the function and output it on the website, I'm still not sure how to approach it. Its just pure javascript at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```js
ReceiveSocket.on('socketMessage', returnedData => {
  // objectsBySocialID always starts empty to make sure that 
  // sendRequest() only receieves new data. Notice that all previous 
  // data was already handled when it arrived, just like the 
  // current batch of data is being handled now.
  const objectsBySocialID = {};

  returnedData.forEach(obj => {
    // If there's already one or more objects with the SocialID of the 
    // current object, then just add it to the array that contains the  
    // objects that have that SocialID.
    if (objectsBySocialID[obj.SocialID]) {
      objectsBySocialID[obj.SocialID].push(obj)
    } 
    // Otherwise, initialize the array that will contain objects with
    // this object's specific SocialID and assign it to the 
    // corresponding key.
    else {
      objectsBySocialID[obj.SocialID] = [obj]
    }

    // objectsBySocialID only contains the latest changes.
    sendRequest(objectsBySocialID);
  });
});
```

Using the data from your example, `objectsBySocialID` should look like this:

```js
{
  '68799': [
    {
      'ID':'4567132',
      'GroupType':'2',
      'Name':'John Chris',
      'SocialID':'68799',
      'SecurityID':'18799-er7ree-781347a-71237n',
    },
    {
      'ID':'4567438',
      'GroupType':'2' ,
      'SocialID':'68799',
      'SecurityID':'68789-4d37er-98c5347-e05d9b',
    },
    {
      'GroupType':'2',
      'SocialID':'68799',
      'PublicSecurityID':'18799-er7ree-781347a-71237n',
      'PrivateSecurityID':'68789-4d37er-98c5347-e05d9b',
    },
  ],
}
```

and when you're done collecting and grouping data, you should be able to pass `objectsBySocialID` as an argument to the function that deals with the ordered data (`sendRequest()` in this example).

Comment: Lastly how can I await for all the request from the socket and only execute once there are no more request. For example I will then pass the data I will call sendRequest() function on the socket it will call the sendRequest() 3 times because 3 message were received. How can I handle the following?

Comment: @John Isn't the app supposed to be running all the time? There should always be new requests unless you shut the server down or people stop using your app. What exactly do you mean with "no more requests"?

Comment: What i mean is what if I called another method or function inside then, lets say 3 messages were received from the socket then I create a function called "sendRequest()" I'll pass the sendRequest(objectsBySocialID). This sendRequest will change the data on the display 3 times. How can pass the values stored in the array or detect any new changes in the data then change the display only once if there is a new or changes in the array.

Comment: I just updated the answer, let me know if there's anything else that needs to be addressed.